# (Python 3) How to extract data from a column with variable number of values in each row in a CSV file?

Tags: python, python3, csv

I have a csv file containing data about movies. In the 'Genres' column, the movie which falls under multiple genres has multiple entries which is split using "|". I want to count the number of movies which fall under any particular genre.

[image: File Screenshot]

Comment: Please add an example of one of your CSV entries for clarification.

Comment: You should add e.g. the first 10 lines of your raw `movies.csv` file. Open it in a text editor like Gedit (not a Spreadsheet editor like LibreOffice Calc) and copy some example lines from it to [edit] your question and add them here. Thanks.

Comment: Question shows no effort from OP, they don't show what they tried nor their desired input and output, potentially a homework. Voting to close

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy yeah, you're probably right. Nakul, could you add the requested information, or show us some sign of life at all?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of getting a count of the number of movies with a specific genre in python. It will have to be adapted for your specific use. I simply imported txt file, split it into a list of lists, and then searched the genre column for the given string.

```
txt = open('file.csv')
contents = txt.read()
contents = contents.split('\n')
new = []
for line in contents:
        new.append(line.split(','))

def searchGenre(contents, genreName):
        count = 0

        for line in contents:
                if genreName in line[genreColumnIndex]:
                        count += 1
                        print(line)

        print(count, " movies of that genre.")

print("searching for horror")
searchGenre(contents, "horror")
```

Comment: apologies just realized you were using python. Let me rewrite.

Comment: I think to avoid a couple of false flags (If a movie has the desired genre in the title), you could say `if genreName in line[index_of_genre_column]`

Comment: yes @ChildishJack that is 100% better. OP should make sure to specify you only search for string in genre column. Even then you could encounter errors, so if necessary you could actually split that column on pipe and then check each genre for match rather than broad column search.